# Conditional types in Typescript with/without generics seems inconsistent

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

While reading the section on [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in the official Typescript Handbook, I came across this behavior in Typscript that I did not understand.

Paraphrasing the example given in the section, here's my example:

```js
type ConditionalType<T> = T extends number ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";  // conditional type defined using generics

// source of confusion
type Result1 = (string | number) extends number ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";   // Result1 is "FAIL"
type Result2 = ConditionalType<string | number>;  // Result2 is "FAIL" | "SUCCESS"

// sanity check
type Result3 = ConditionalType<number>;  // Result3 is "SUCCESS"
type Result4 = ConditionalType<boolean>;  // Result4 is "FAIL"
```

Here's a recreation of the above example on the official Typescript playground: [[LINK]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&q=469#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYBVwQA8uAfFALxS5QQAewEyAzlAgK4C2ARhAE5QB+KACIAygFUYMAKKjRwqAC4RAMQCCASQAywgNxQoAekNQAxolTos2KKEhQkEAGYoEEJFDZNXAcyg-GPhRTJgBYACgI4ygmODZeU2g4JzNEJy8MBAi7aAAlCCY2bGAARgooAAomYF5fKAAfVk4eXgBKGnpGJBZ2bj5BEQkpWXklVU0dfQNo-MLispQWYXVtYWyCKFmi4AAmcvhkNEycfEhCatqEP0belpIpmYLtvcXx1YbByRk5Ncjw6KYmAQaBAZgAFhBTABrdb2LbFADM+wsR2spyItz492mJnhwCRrzEXxGvxymyexQALMjDlYECcCIQuHA4NgIEDsUZcRTgNTCSsdBEgA)

I don't understand why `Result1` and `Result2` are different. According to me, `Result2` should also have been `"FAIL"`.

Comment: In reference to the handbook, I believe the `extends` actually refers to the union `number | string`. I don't think a `number` type is extendable, but maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: @MarioVernari irrespective of what `extends` means, my question is why  are`Result1` and `Result2` different? They're reasoning over the same types. The only difference is whether they're using generics or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a consequence of a section a bit lower namely [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

Basically if typescript sees a condition over a naked type parameters (such as `T`) and if `T` is a union, it will apply the conditional type to each constituent of the union and union the results.

So we have:

```
type Result2 = ConditionalType<string | number> 
    ≡ ConditionalType<string> | ConditionalType<number>
    ≡ (string extends number ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL") | (number extends number ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL")
    ≡ "FAIL" | "SUCCESS"
```

This will not happen for `Result1` where the condition is over a type not a type parameter, so inlining a conditional type can produce different results.

We can get the same behavior if we introduce a type parameter in the inlined version:

```
type Result1 = (string | number) extends infer T ? T extends number ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL" : never;   // Result1 is "FAIL" | "SUCCESS"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&q=469#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYBVwQA8uAfFALxS5QQAewEyAzlAgK4C2ARhAE5QB+KACIAygFUYMAKKjRwqAC4RAMQCCASQAywgNxQoAekNQAxolTos2KKEhQkEAGYoEEJFDZNXAcyg-GPhRTJgBYACgI4ygmODZeU2g4JzNEJy8MBAi7aAAlCCY2bGAARgooAAomYF5fKAAfVk4eXgBKOgZmKFcnPiohag7GJBZ2bj6hMUkZOQVlYXVtOdYIADc+fQNo-MLispQWBc0dBpEJKVl5bIIoHaLgACZy+GQ0TJx8SEJq2oQ-RrGLRIm22BXuTwOqmOCkaUwuswiURMTEwCDQIDMAAsIKYANbXex3YoAZmeFje1k+REBfGBWxMROApMhcJmV3COVuYOKABYya8rAgPgRCFw4HBsBBUXSjAzucA+SzFjoIkA)

In the example above, `infer T` will introduce a new type parameter that will contain the type on the left side of `extends` in this case `string | number`

We can also disable distribution for the conditional type if we wrap the type parameter in a tuple:

```
type ConditionalType<T> = [T] extends [number] ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";  // conditional type defined using generics
type Result2 = ConditionalType<string | number>;  // Result2 is "FAIL"

// sanity check
type Result3 = ConditionalType<number>;  // Result3 is "SUCCESS"
type Result4 = ConditionalType<boolean>;  // Result4 is "FAIL"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&q=469#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYBVwQA8uAfFALxQDauAulBAB7ATIDO1CArgLYBGEAE70A-FABEAZQCqMGAFFJk8VABcEgGIBBAJIAZcQG4oUAPSmoAY0Sp0WbFFCQoSCADMUCCEihc2ngHMoANYhFEs2AFgAKCdoACUINi5sYAAmClgbNAwEHHxIQjZgQUCoAB8obn4hEmMzC0Tk1IyUDnFtfXEYmPMoNkwENBArAAsISwBrGLioJpTgAGZM+GQc+wKiaoFBOpM++dTltokZOUVlGYI5pIWAFhXsuzy8AkI+ODhsCEG9hpvmsAHicOroDDEgA)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! And thanks for the additional info about inline type parameters and wrapping them in tuples.

Comment: Having said that, I don't understand WHY Typescript defaults to distributing over union types. It just seems a bit inconsistent to treat types differently when using type parameters vs explicit types. The handbook mentions that "typically, distributivity is the desired behavior", but doesn't motivate why that is.

Comment: @user1814274 it's a design decision. They could have used a specialized syntax, they chose to distribute as the default as in most cases this  is the intuitively expected result.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't know the conditional types, but now I learn something new!

You're passing an union of possible types to the `ConditionalType`, thus the actual constraint is not known.

It becomes more clear as in the handbook example:

```
function test<T extends number | string>(): ConditionalType<T> {
   throw new Error();
}

const z1 = test<string>();  //FAIL
const z2 = test<number>();  //SUCCESS
```

The same function gives two possible results upon the generic argument type.

For `Result1`, everything is known: no parameters, no variability, hence the result is also known.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer doesn't really make sense and it isn't the correct answer to the question. The "actual constraint" is `number | string`, and there is no sense in which either the constraint or the result is not "known". The other answer is correct.